# Complex query in template of django

Tags: django

I have model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    @property
    def user(self):
        return Users.objects.using('second_db').get(pk=self.sender)
```

In template:

```
{% comment %}
    message_list = Message.objects.all().select_related("thread")
{% endcomment %}

{% for message in message_list %}
   {{ message.text }}
   {{ message.thread.name }}
   {{ message.user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Line `{{ message.user.name }}` makes query sql. This is reduces the performance of the app.
There are tables "users" and "message" in the different databases.
How to improve peformance of app?
Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably give yourself more flexibility if you kept the main query out of the template and in viewcode.  As to db design, many messages in a fetch that have many users whose name are stored in another db....    Consider denormalizing and putting usernames in message.  Might need to update them on name changes later.

Comment: Why not use `select_related` on the `user` also?

Comment: JL, your idea is very convenient. There are 8000 users + 50-100 user/day in the project. What to do if user himself changes username?

Answer (score 2):

Prefetch the related data manually (from N+1 -> 3 queries).

```
thread_ids = [message.thread_id for message in message_list]
user_ids = [message.user_id for message in message_list]

users = {u.id: u for u in User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)}
threads = {t.id for t in Thread.objects.filter(id__in=thread_ids)}
```

Then you can either pass the users and threads dicts to your template, or loop over messages and attach them manually

```
for message in message_list:
    message.thread = threads.get(message.thread_id)
    message.user = users.get(message.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you should have it in one DB or use caching, but there is no way you can reduce the query.

I would probably go with caching. You could also somehow prefetch the user in **init** but I am not sure if that is the good idea. This is simply bad design.